# Polymorphism and overriding confusion

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism, overriding

Recently My teacher was teaching Polymorphism and he taught that there are two aspects in Polymorphism as

1. Run-time Polymorphism
2. Compile-time Polymorphism

And then He showed us this code

```
class A {
    void ab(){
        System.out.println("ab() in class A");
    }
}

class B extends A {
    void ab(){
        System.out.println("ab() in class B");
    }
}

class ObCo {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        A a1 = new B();
        a1.ab();
    }
}
```

The output is `ab() in class B`

And when I try the following code,

```
class A {
    int i = 10;
}

class B extends A {
    int i = 100;
}

class ObCo {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        A a1 = new B();
        System.out.println(a1.i);
    }
}
```

According to the previous code, the output should be `100` But the output is `10` Which rises up these questions in my mind.

1. Is Polymorphism a concept only related to Overriding methods?
2. Is the first code block relevant to Polymorphism?
3. If yes, what is run-time Polymorphism and compile-time Polymorphism?
4. If no, please give me an example where Polymorphism is seen.

Detailed answers on those questions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: At compile time the compiler checks whether the reference variable a1 has a method named ab(). At runtime the actual object passed is B's instance, so the overridden method of B is used for processing.

Answer (score 4):

Polymorphism applies to non-static non-final **methods** only. The code you tried is not polymorphism but [field hiding](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/hidevariables.html) (emphasis mine):

> **Within a class, a field that has the same name as a field in the superclass hides the superclass's field, even if their types are different.** Within the subclass, the field in the superclass cannot be referenced by its simple name. Instead, the field must be accessed through super, which is covered in the next section. Generally speaking, we don't recommend hiding fields as it makes code difficult to read.

With this in mind, answers to your questions:

> 1. Is Polymorphism a concept only related to Overriding methods?

Yes.

> 2. Is the first code block is relevant to Polymorphism?

Yes.

> 3. If yes, What is run-time Polymorphism and compile-time Polymorphism?

In Java, all non-`static` non-`final` methods are [virtual methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function) by default, so if a subclass has a method with the **same** [signature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_signature) (same input types, same output type) that the super class, this method is being overridden even if that wasn't your intention. The compiler will even raise a warning stating that the method in the subclass must use the `@Override` annotation to inform other programmers that this method is being overridden.

In Java, according to this tutorial, it's called *compile time polymorphism* to method overloading (such an odd name).

> 4.If no, Please give me an example where Polymorphism is seen.

You already have such example for method overriding (dynamic).

Here's another example for method overloading (static):

```
public class Foo {
    public void print(int x) {
        System.out.println("Printing number: " + x);
    }
    public void print(String x) {
        System.out.println("Printing string: " + x);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        foo.print(5);
        foo.print("5");
    }
}
```

Output:

> Printing number: 5
>   Printing string: 5

Comment: Isn't defining foo(int) and foo(float) within a class an example of compile time poymorphism? (I agree the idea is usually associated with c++ template usage but the call is chosen at compile time according to the type)

Comment: @Elemental that's not overriding, it's overloading since those methods do not have the same signature. Already edited the post.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Is Polymorphism a concept only related to Overriding methods?

Polymorphism applies to METHODS only. To **non-static** and **non-final** **METHODS**.

> 2. Is the first code block is relevant to Polymorphism?

Not really, in first block you don't override, you hide the `ab()` method. It's the rules in [section 8.4.8.3 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.3), "Requirements in Overriding and Hiding":

> 3. If yes, What is run-time Polymorphism and compile-time Polymorphism?

---

> 4. If no, Please give me an example where Polymorphism is seen.

Better than writting a fast code, check [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_polymorphism.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Your questions:

> Is Polymorphism a concept only related to Overriding methods?

Yes - Java only implements polymorphism on methods of classes. The way you tried it on a data type doesn't work.

> Is the first code block is relevant to Polymorphism?

Yes, it's a pretty typical example of run-time polymorphism,

> If yes, What is run-time Polymorphism and compile-time Polymorphism?

Your working example is a typical run time situation. We call this run-time because only when the code is actually running can we figure out that a1 is actually a instance of B not an instance of A

Compile-time polymorphism is the situation when one method is chosen over another method with the same name when the code is compiled because of the types associated with it.